Passing Structure Directly to Void Pointer
I know that a void pointer is useful for setting up generic functions etc.  In any case, I also understand that a void pointer can be used to directly point to things like integers etc.  I suspect that a void pointer can also be used to point to structure items as well; however, I can't seem to get the semantics related to a passing a void pointer into a structure.  Specifically, i'm trying to change fcat.test from 200 to 300 by using the void pointer.  No-matter, which permutation of casting i use, I get the following error "main.c:12:15: error: request for member ‘test’ in something not a structure or union." How do I go about accessing a structure via a void pointer and changing the values within it?  My code is below.
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct _cat{
    int test;
}cat;

int main()
{
cat fcat;
fcat.test=200;
void * pointer=NULL;
pointer=&fcat;  //This works
*((cat)pointer.test)=300; //I can't seem to figure out how to get 300 into the function via the void pointer.  I've tried (cat *) as the typecast along with the -> operator after pointer.  Nothing works.
}


((cat *)pointer)->test = 300  -- just need to remember that prefix ops (like cast) are lower precedence than postfix (like ->)

That works, thank you!  How do I know when to use the instance of the struct vs the struct type?  Both ((cat *)pointer)->test = 300 and ((struct _cat *)pointer)->test=300 work.  Regardless, you're response works.

Because of the typedef struct _cat and cat are the same thing and interchangeable in all cases.
